# Project creation / deletion, what's the proper way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently started messing around with Ruby and Rails.  I have created several ruby projects / "webapps" by issuing the following command, `rails new <project_name>`  I ran that command in several different directories on my local WebServer, as I have been working through several rails tutorials.  What have been doing to delete the project is deleting the directory that contains all the scaffolding files created by the command listed above.  *Is there a more appropriate way to list the rails projects I have created, and is there a more appropriate way to delete the project created using the command above?*

I recently created a project in my local *webroot* then did a `rm -rf` on the created project.  I then decided to work through the tutorial again, and when I ran `rails new <project_name>` the files I created from the previous tutorial seemed to have restored.  I was hoping to start a fresh project.  *Why is the rails restoring the project I previously created, and how would I start a fresh project with the same name?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails new command creates all of these files and directories by default on every new project.

```
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
```

If you recursively delete the project, it will not retain anything from a previous Rails project.  One quick way to find all "potential" Rails projects is to use the find command like this.

```
find ~ -name "filter_parameter_logging.rb" -not -path "*/.rbenv/*" -not -path "*/.rvm/*"
```

This should find all Rails projects in your home directory, and not find any related files in your rbenv or rvm paths.  You could pass in the -exec rm {} \; option at the end if you'd like to remove them at the same time, but I would rather locate them and remove the projects by hand.

Comment: I ran the above command, `find ~ -name "filter_parameter_logging.rb" -not -path "*/.rbenv/*" -not -path "*/.rvm/*"` and it returned no results even though I created a rails project in the root directory of my web server.  If it makes a difference I'm running Ruby 2.0.x and rails 3.2.13 on OS X 10.8.4

Comment: The `~` in the command above means the search begins in your home folder. If you are creating projects at the root replace it with `/`. It will probably take a while to complete.

Comment: This is exactly right.  You shouldn't be making new Rails apps in the root directory, you should be making them in your user's director.  I use Mac's for all of my Rails development.  I'd create a folder for your apps in your user directory, and set them up there, in a consistent location. cd && mkdir -p ~/rails_apps && cd ~/rails_apps && rails new <project_name>

Comment: I am creating the Ruby apps in the web server root for the machine, which I believe is at `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`

Comment: @Alex.Bullard thanks for the helpful suggestion on the command above.

Comment: I would consider not putting your apps there, but that's fine if you want to. That path really isn't / anyways.  You could change Alex's followup to my find script and replace the ~ with /Library/WebServer/Documents/